# jquery not executing in browser

Tags: jquery

My this code runs ok in jsfiddle but not in browser. Can anyone help me on it ?

```
$(".menuitem").hover(function() {
$(this).children("span").fadeIn();
}, function() {
$(this).children("span").fadeOut();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PmV6x/

Thanks

Comment: What browser? Open developer console/firebug (F12 in most cases), check out the console for any logs/errors, post here.

Comment: Is your `jQuery` code placed before `body`?

Comment: Are you including the jQuery.js? Just making sure, I've seen it happen alot

Comment: I strongly recommend to read the jQuery **documentation** which explains how to set up your code properly: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menuitem").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("span").fadeIn();
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("span").fadeOut();
    })
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PmV6x/1/)

The problem is that these statements are never called in your code, they are loaded before the actual DOM. At this time your code does not find the DOM elements it is looking for, hence no elements are selected and no event is attached to any elements.

Comment: what u mean by statements being called and being loaded plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating your code in this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //your code
});
```

**jsfiddle** automatically encapsulates your code in `$(document).ready()`. That must be why its working there.

Answer (score 0):

You want add your code inside

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
 .
 . 

});
```

this event.So when your DOM is ready then your code is execute.

Also make sure you add jquery default library file like jquery.js.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't forget to add jQuery to your page.
- Don't forget to wait for document ready.

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My jQuery Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $(".menuitem").hover(function() {
                    $(this).children("span").fadeIn();
                }, function() {
                    $(this).children("span").fadeOut();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- YOUR HTML -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added jquery reference to your page first and add some content to your menuitem spans and add style="display:none" style to your span. You may want to change the styles to get display spans correctly.

```
<li class="menuitem"><span style="display:none">Your image 01</span>ITEM 01</li>
<li class="menuitem"><span style="display:none">Your image 02</span>ITEM 02</li>
```

And also wrap your code with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```