# How to trigger a function when a label value is changed in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have several labels with a specific class. I would like to trigger a javascript function when the label text is changed via jQuery. How can I trigger a function when a label value is changed in jQuery? I have tried the following to no avail:

```
$(".className").Change(function () {
    $(this).Change(function () {
        calculate();
    });
});
```

Comment: How does the user change the label value?

Comment: Typically what you are looking for is called observable, but its a performance killer. The way to go is when changing label value, trigger a custom event.

Comment: Its `change()` not `.Change()`. Also you don't need a `nested` `$(this).change()`

Comment: Just call the method when the javascript changes the value. You don't need an event handler (nor can you have one).

Comment: Label value displaying by adding another two values in the text box.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav label don't have any change event, i think OP want to write a pseudo code here

Comment: First of all, JavaScript is case sensitive. A jQuery method `change` exists, but not `Change`. Then, why are you trying to binding yet anbother `Change` event handler to the element after a `Change` event was triggered? That doesn't seem to make sense. As already mentioned, just call the function you want to have called after you changed the text of the label.

Comment: another solution is to fire a custom event like `mylabelchange` after changing the value of the label ex: `$('.className').on('mylabelchange', function(){dosomething})` then `$('.className').html('update').triggerHandler('mylabelchange')`

Comment: Show the code for where you change the label text (or just call the calculate function from there)

Comment: @roasted: Yes, but OP has used proper `jQuery` format thats why I just tried to remind him that there is no such thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is not working!

`The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.`

And a label has no attribute `value` it is no `<input>`, `<textarea>` or `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to trigger a function when a label value is changed in Jquery?

By simply calling the function after you changed the label text.

```
$label.text('New label text');
calculate();
```

Modifying the content of an element does not trigger a `change` event. That's an event only triggered by form control elements.

Answer (score 0):

change event is browser initiated, so here to receive value change events you need to initiate custom change event. Here i assume label is any `div`, `p` or `span` like element.

```
$(".className").change(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                calculate();
           });
 });
```

create your custome event observer like this.

```
var oldVal = "";
$(function({
   setInterval(Observe,200); // waits for change to happen
}))

function Observe(){
if($(".className").text() != oldVal){
         $(".className").trigger('change');
       }
       oldVal = $(".className").text();
}
```

Comment: You have to pass the function, not call it: `setInterval(Observe,200);`.

Answer (score -2):

The letter case is probably the issue here.
Try jQuery function `change()` (starting with a small letter)

Comment: Even `change` is not working

Comment: @JohnStephen: I think think question will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996563/jquery-not-executing-in-browser/16996582#16996582

Comment: `change` is not working because `change` doesnt support `label`. it supports only `input and select etc`

Comment: @Digvijay: No, that's not the problem.